# Run function in R that requires two elements and want to compare two by two

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I know this might be a pretty simple automatic iterative question.

I am running a PLS regression by using *geomorph*.

This function requires [two 3D arrays](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geomorph/versions/3.0.2/topics/two.b.pls?) inside it (`A1` and `A2`), as can be seen in the documentation in the previous link.

Basically the function would be:

`two.b.pls(A1, A2, iter = 999)`

The point is that I am having 8 different 3D matrix arrays and want to run the PLS analysis for any possible combination.

More explicitly, if my arrays are named `Group_1`, `Group_2`... `Group_8`, what I need is to iteratively analyse these combinations:

```
two.b.pls(Group_1, Group_2, iter = 999)
two.b.pls(Group 1, Group 3, iter = 999)
...
two.b.pls(Group_7, Group_8, iter = 999)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have object names in a vector, use `combn` to return the pairwise combinations, `get` the values and pass them into `two.b.pls` function

```
nm1 <- c('Frontal', 'Face', 'Parietal_L', 'Parietal_R', 'Temporal_L', 'Temporal_R', 'Occipital', 'Sphenoid')
out <- combn(nm1, 2, FUN = function(x)
     two.b.pls(get(x[1]), get(x[2]), iter = 999), simplify = FALSE)
```

If we want to get the combination name, an option is to `name` the `list` elements with `combn` output of the vector

```
names(out) <- combn(nm1, 2, FUN = paste, collapse="_")
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, however you are right, the names are different and not `Group_x`. They are all named differently. How can I proceed then? They are named `c(Frontal, Face, Parietal_L, Parietal_R, Temporal_L, Temporal_R, Occipital, Sphenoid)`

Comment: @antecessor then get the names of that object in a vector and use that in combn i.e. `nm1 <- c("a1", "group1", "hello", "away"); combn(nm1, 2, FUN = ...`

Comment: I tried this: `out <- combn(c(Frontal, Face, Parietal_L, Parietal_R, Temporal_L, Temporal_R, Occipital, Sphenoid), 2, FUN = function(x)
   two.b.pls(get(x[1]), get(x[2]), iter = 999), simplify = FALSE)` with no success.

Comment: That's perfect. I forgot the quotation marks!

Comment: Extra question @akrun. When I see the `out` output I cannot see which is the combitation employed in each iteration. How could I proceed?

Comment: @antecessor you can named it with the combn of the object names as in the updated post

Comment: @antecessor have you tried this step `names(out) <- combn(nm1, 2, FUN = paste, collapse="_")`  then the `out` will have names instead of unnamed list

Comment: SOmetimes the html won't update if it is not refreshed