# Compare automatically all possible combinations (1 vs 1) (1 vs 1+2), etc in a function in R

Tags: r, lapply, pls

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199807/run-function-in-r-that-requires-two-elements-and-want-to-compare-two-by-two/69199835#69199835), and with the same example, I would like to modify the groups in the comparison.

Just to remember, I am running a PLS regression by using *geomorph*.

This function requires [two 3D arrays](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geomorph/versions/3.0.2/topics/two.b.pls?) inside it (`A1` and `A2`), as can be seen in the documentation in the previous link.

Basically the function would be:

`two.b.pls(A1, A2, iter = 999)`

The point is that I am having 8 different 3D matrix arrays and want to run the PLS analysis for any possible combination.

The difference with my previous question is the type of combinations. My arrays are named `Group_1`, `Group_2`... `Group_8`. I wanted earlier to compare `Group_1` vs. `Group_2` etc, but now I need to compare all combinations as possible by combining the groups, for instance, `Group_1` vs. `Group_2`+`Group_3`, etc. What I need is to iteratively explore all possible combinations:

```
two.b.pls(Group_1, Group_2, iter = 999)
two.b.pls(Group 1, Group 3, iter = 999)
two.b.pls(Group 1, Group 2 + Group 3, iter = 999)
...
two.b.pls(Group_7, Group_8, iter = 999)
```

**Minor comment on the combinations required**

- `Group_1 vs. Group_2` (and all the combinations 1 by 1)
- `Group_1 vs. Group_2&Group_3` (combined) (and all the combinations 1 by 2)
- `Group_1 vs. Group_2&Group_3&Group_4` (combined) (and all the combinations 1 by 3)
- ...
- `Group_1 vs. Group_2&Group_3&...&Group_8` (combined)

Another set:

- `Group_1&Group_2 vs. Group_3&Group_4` (combined) (and all the combinations 2 by 2).
- ...
- `Group_1&Group_2&Group_3&Group_4 vs. Group_5&Group_6`
- ...

Specifications:

- `Group_1 vs. Group_2&Group_3` == `Group_2&Group_3 vs. Group_1`
- `Group_1 vs. Group_2&Group_3` == `Group_1 vs. Group_3&Group_2`

#### 3D array as example

Please, download this example. Create `Face`, `Frontal` and the other groups with this same dataset. This is the structure of this example `num [1:112, 1:3, 1:2]`

```
structure(c(0.0121067537295831, -0.0139329378363627, -0.0128942856218092, 
0.00104644154378343, -0.00114530915378115, -0.000607912100374409, 
0.00151278447681022, 0.00393687340838906, 0.00621298060827974, 
0.00834044621831124, 0.0102092935435389, 0.0115755766569844, 
0.0119258892059719, -0.000396743612783844, 0.00185330841923162, 
0.00435613976082836, 0.00683328855687188, 0.0093417626098382, 
0.0110196500804907, 0.0119338477285669, 0.0122282953973805, 0.00970016937702731, 
0.00502149702279466, 6.43342133087913e-05, -0.00492288184466163, 
-0.00956756783898905, -0.0135047050650378, -0.0162386438360501, 
-0.0182130797956816, -0.0194252658586714, -0.019956478468564, 
-0.0195560089784483, -0.0194376122541402, -0.0189496884694952, 
-0.0188076982059598, -0.0184481816461359, -0.0178127383586681, 
-0.0172051565198613, -0.0162368638401209, -0.0169731739342895, 
-0.017597312625215, -0.0180638542635129, -0.0187144293475924, 
-0.0189884753925375, -0.0189947938350846, -0.0193729916935741, 
-0.0193636556951379, -0.00408430404773437, -0.00664029045820733, 
-0.00892836358740464, -0.0106234245916282, -0.0114889308750888, 
-0.0123253175220186, -0.00239864086586122, -0.00548067506615771, 
-0.00841302150977786, -0.0110588381511544, -0.0125741839608042, 
-0.0132378724743151, -0.0143350819811742, -0.0151336998776877, 
-0.0163526630884662, -0.0177165720198144, -0.0191285732564418, 
-0.019944892329024, -0.0199324039287649, -0.0202185556327263, 
-0.0190696924697975, -0.0173547483350903, -0.0159511654761443, 
-0.0147291258658671, -0.0137233248776445, -0.0203200694852889, 
-0.0184506889252457, -0.0158203449430831, -0.0196266755955667, 
-0.0209659699612106, -0.0205698543045638, -0.0183129557213343, 
-0.0162673719891882, -0.0204944283453325, -0.0168984523237582, 
-0.0172784962660288, -0.0204264167160555, -0.0205440506730952, 
-0.0187558434048595, -0.0152092221518476, -0.0203970113196534, 
-0.0176357135428962, -0.0193952758042404, -0.0198037508808749, 
-0.0203583856042399, -0.0208134667944455, -0.0150492447642772, 
-0.0152602566994186, -0.0191844556313852, -0.0175986034747731, 
-0.016240690926133, -0.017582868965997, 0.000203505568249415, 
-0.00268512269701802, -0.0131454051941203, -0.0125643151022891, 
-0.00511531931380859, -0.00203280827772074, 0.00320590657051683, 
-0.00626169715789532, -0.000668437780500823, -0.019380055733749, 
-0.00446052160041499, -0.0199727808288008, 0.00379018316863347, 
9.57128256764846e-05, 0.0176615324865033, -0.0183982515354167, 
0.021955722685282, -0.0208609214574232, -0.0216249847657198, 
-0.0215160559748617, -0.0202098811465698, -0.0182993603255582, 
-0.0153881733371962, -0.0119849076726351, -0.00826706040213423, 
-0.00411105738294977, 0.0216232694815021, 0.0212626099454012, 
0.0197639705630097, 0.0177457724953735, 0.0151158131692247, 0.0118629656679233, 
0.00798339321420489, 0.00403919891236629, 6.93300838151236e-05, 
-6.59969168921038e-05, -0.000176322187804505, -0.000214470519799677, 
-0.000140138774905899, -6.95124715839799e-05, -6.07152549401866e-05, 
-0.000121751691618514, -0.000190949191335675, -0.00420221113412627, 
-0.0046546857014779, -0.00590803504983574, -0.00742390203482344, 
-0.00955164077502198, -0.0116210651143029, -0.0136246811967233, 
-0.0153597202783619, -0.016520473599831, 0.0158209294861601, 
0.0144805016874292, 0.0127699288459808, 0.0108665503181813, 0.00880050918667468, 
0.00682965250590193, 0.00522906142230795, 0.00398456393406205, 
-0.0196649104672861, -0.0186792178514035, -0.0175459563818717, 
-0.0173203337783667, -0.017526142565625, -0.0179761177459468, 
0.0210626606617924, 0.0197037576394902, 0.0177482641644597, 0.0169824449782621, 
0.0171492142644067, 0.0173799507697275, 0.0175807822049577, 0.0166591521159536, 
0.0144723059446465, 0.0117073399302622, 0.00836867344687509, 
0.00420619178673691, -0.000475512210001711, -0.00513522463858741, 
-0.0096513057207465, -0.0129065159907077, -0.0156326089300706, 
-0.0177622453535592, -0.0183883852720748, 0.00483575892339502, 
0.0109585351836108, 0.0169248421290258, 0.00739883809085566, 
-0.000311708220811525, -0.00496356370416955, 0.012671019230947, 
-0.0162277686974197, 0.00282026501947482, -0.0165380742333304, 
0.0143504752307859, -0.00311853282722531, 0.0013439133424226, 
-0.0110193704417722, -0.0179826972534614, 0.00484808074784459, 
-0.0144688771464215, -0.0091834907261722, -0.00761739209299819, 
-0.00458104863708919, -0.00237537440293526, 0.0177086490258444, 
-0.0176924574890119, 0.00933439446690749, -0.0129201731056937, 
0.017049918790561, 0.0154059190489952, -0.00725653105931065, 
-0.0168114167454652, 0.0173954364309373, -0.0184093777902411, 
-0.00692227950521597, 0.0135066524432826, -0.0200377340229696, 
-0.0192924918628568, 0.0189953682053652, 0.0065920411043607, 
0.0207763069491844, -0.00490970221726531, 0.0070342803679922, 
-0.0299656339772703, -0.00781014999662473, -0.00742460195002254, 
-0.00852379235397777, -0.00770814329844858, -0.0128968190500875, 
-0.0169069261502681, -0.0199654117248723, -0.022833066018448, 
-0.0252541610417436, -0.0273094681489095, -0.0289140751399086, 
-0.029571942393349, -0.0131156818675002, -0.0168783584731727, 
-0.0197229377982092, -0.0222949528843976, -0.0246155933705453, 
-0.0270213460442498, -0.0286139332093845, -0.0298522067412257, 
-0.0306936892402078, -0.0312245434915385, -0.0311144376344305, 
-0.0301558790063451, -0.0283325451325485, -0.0255757771780149, 
-0.0221547869099635, -0.0190107068572344, -0.0170655364750566, 
-0.0085992823261642, -0.00983147288183302, -0.0113196124238418, 
-0.012606851536613, -0.0127016336390267, -0.0121251647817931, 
-0.0114146883856852, -0.010295370079425, -0.00886051780892385, 
-0.00911491927806971, -0.0103800514545884, -0.0113789519665083, 
-0.0120041072141714, -0.0124770003431828, -0.0122568444076323, 
-0.0111393316963931, -0.00980229783172321, -0.00757396956404178, 
-0.00746826930600419, -0.00753079445983466, -0.00752512063965866, 
-0.00748527714103993, -0.00742021392749337, -0.00837814516441945, 
-0.00815176012587459, -0.00787115435263527, -0.00777995325147563, 
-0.00782374041923372, -0.00785425926668388, -0.00967021213344859, 
-0.0118236999226699, -0.0134653423972038, -0.0151978835551724, 
-0.0166422891034175, -0.0171478960392589, -0.016908540157026, 
-0.0172903692640931, -0.016696130263402, -0.0151145154994161, 
-0.0131913922017915, -0.0110621643620987, -0.00906678245018461, 
-0.0157232922354404, -0.0143582255771394, -0.0106592633110684, 
-0.0157301827812935, -0.0137704426813924, -0.0161561119929206, 
-0.0123502372809837, -0.0120404772183872, -0.011205924393612, 
-0.0102236037598132, -0.0125646792086793, -0.00985264666590227, 
-0.0159946450762133, -0.0134197891804638, -0.00988036482173798, 
-0.0129789017819308, -0.0120314631340899, -0.0156257547247481, 
-0.0144193728249802, -0.0120215924211333, -0.0157810207816036, 
-0.00852616880899861, -0.00788467249309025, -0.01356536007035, 
-0.0143121132018561, -0.0083066837625688, -0.0108417415256806, 
-0.0301955476848072, -0.0241434062218676, -0.0122943605337793, 
-0.00775612886007838, -0.0290228197328159, -0.0259454272736183, 
-0.0208885324020887, -0.00853199509771019, -0.021016347241584, 
-0.0174833113107165, -0.0132131738700254, -0.0176623249942278, 
-0.0303206618263515, 0.0127776364853376, -0.0152452243000105, 
-0.0147105852230956, -0.000863874408630801, -0.000209885807261966, 
-0.000331581547817195, 0.000501913076487955, 0.00280122318386634, 
0.00586278420222562, 0.00884948590623061, 0.0110321835800337, 
0.0121504087239398, 0.0126238643777473, -0.00116678400949535, 
0.000309098039122892, 0.00274365192850091, 0.00536277214780085, 
0.00787276641694412, 0.00994463037319537, 0.0117030008228836, 
0.0127848253859643, 0.0102434336168691, 0.00536484343949205, 
0.000262677005211979, -0.00475716562751991, -0.0092856945102185, 
-0.0131277374842598, -0.0160383460447621, -0.0183311058353516, 
-0.0197199548288722, -0.0198559128532786, -0.0198579400897286, 
-0.0200326661395768, -0.0194686440260956, -0.019396466558016, 
-0.0193168686399384, -0.018836091216227, -0.0184061172416965, 
-0.0175896108878106, -0.0182014405947427, -0.0185988791253094, 
-0.0187820813333505, -0.0190165366997682, -0.0190174031419613, 
-0.0192544802580697, -0.0198412223742528, -0.019758033447168, 
-0.00320133118204574, -0.00615476035279051, -0.00937984850181281, 
-0.0119227278138075, -0.0134572187644259, -0.014266707013781, 
-0.00320248689735123, -0.00593510789800099, -0.00913687701439053, 
-0.0121478179417917, -0.0140997195693407, -0.0148624470466123, 
-0.0162853478207419, -0.0169558670069506, -0.0171485021492836, 
-0.0179293084780989, -0.0189236569302454, -0.0200280979178052, 
-0.0201835513258776, -0.0203155932654009, -0.0190617340444641, 
-0.0176470469832613, -0.0167847173642825, -0.0162820395311557, 
-0.0154790628049744, -0.0204204848345239, -0.0188209658483633, 
-0.0175505053387551, -0.0195717677446563, -0.021179463511248, 
-0.0208786568169446, -0.019069560636353, -0.0173645780141257, 
-0.0206194278230603, -0.0182266456298993, -0.0182349521436495, 
-0.0203936090235412, -0.020773374166366, -0.0194125058845639, 
-0.0168809938214606, -0.0205941325139531, -0.0185866626526175, 
-0.0196528192035162, -0.0202849258298999, -0.0210914618991165, 
-0.0210384427398307, -0.0166286873932309, -0.0168834667354705, 
-0.0193889694262657, -0.0180990834649523, -0.0177420142623336, 
-0.018800405940245, 0.000523501896703479, -0.0029261097264044, 
-0.0146321688981797, -0.0145531489430636, -0.00494439965759757, 
-0.00284250195686774, 0.00225485514966812, -0.00595669409878074, 
-0.00185724176389381, -0.019252019103788, -0.00539562893555244, 
-0.0200498867260231, 0.00350463890855844, 0.00100525471102834, 
0.017071734313362, -0.0180797098086776, 0.0212141654154872, -0.0213160923807591, 
-0.0212957182248067, -0.0214662450855171, -0.0199465405608737, 
-0.0182343573421267, -0.0154570896926197, -0.0120083526857707, 
-0.00780487511046493, -0.00339017439997714, 0.0209368593999181, 
0.020588563526874, 0.01913362662387, 0.0174819046855605, 0.0151727297678676, 
0.0120622439286332, 0.00854192437336988, 0.00477549549417729, 
0.000959514886792293, 0.00086367959534621, 0.000733910218756855, 
0.000556459985315933, 0.000368212110990821, 0.000167290914129546, 
-4.96631069309189e-05, -0.000257642952562252, -0.000393942844978405, 
-0.00370568556096609, -0.00423737604809828, -0.00562884468972012, 
-0.00717879773073304, -0.00924653564959142, -0.0113927508863948, 
-0.0134073925813304, -0.015185546576351, -0.0163707369270519, 
0.0152290436102138, 0.0138448530426031, 0.01205637447214, 0.0100153951166161, 
0.00788519518442069, 0.0057407469258699, 0.00409262353568515, 
0.00271017228405623, -0.0198288941212281, -0.0186318757659544, 
-0.0172712409469645, -0.0162335941301901, -0.0164126097070513, 
-0.0173771169051665, 0.020109104090643, 0.0187101345999028, 0.0167105166543032, 
0.0152575143210133, 0.0156886432759352, 0.0165319022262677, 0.0171582245693941, 
0.0162280492120763, 0.0141315427138271, 0.0112493507713461, 0.00773343947298834, 
0.00371546401835653, -0.000659605057928003, -0.00499491955935594, 
-0.0092477714337454, -0.0125017521159196, -0.0151786508806214, 
-0.0173865957635562, -0.0181793392041093, 0.0041939912863222, 
0.0104873358804602, 0.0166973173151379, 0.00671499620031813, 
-0.000587338004291861, -0.00486544441698405, 0.0121136769140914, 
-0.0159046406153872, 0.00191901645180105, -0.0163693673725423, 
0.0139924440541622, -0.00279045214703507, 0.000952406008266023, 
-0.0107832055228765, -0.0179357102553364, 0.00393811167380723, 
-0.0142708811035892, -0.00888102060955728, -0.00737323885894898, 
-0.00446214895976684, -0.00245190564496676, 0.0172248556504535, 
-0.0176757128782511, 0.00863985006836693, -0.0126206510681342, 
0.0166394585376546, 0.014952572452408, -0.00657700188211858, 
-0.0161911771734234, 0.0161059208508412, -0.0178817032028216, 
-0.00629111535992669, 0.0133969495769111, -0.0194959868885208, 
-0.0192009607384602, 0.0181259301303218, 0.00600314788573458, 
0.0197613597582916, -0.0047787506936498, 0.00745721889807159, 
-0.0292291332920766, -0.00812087569534304, -0.00743611172635218, 
-0.00885413422418974, -0.00777937002763539, -0.0126982336492491, 
-0.0169399947077556, -0.0202311363446088, -0.0229456543081723, 
-0.0249878361884412, -0.0269907846948384, -0.0282628825010996, 
-0.0290363401578354, -0.0133268120739664, -0.01728453720012, 
-0.0200285728729878, -0.0223837116395661, -0.0246147905484459, 
-0.0264508728197877, -0.0277270947907398, -0.0286012275090666, 
-0.0296560667420954, -0.0302363823717699, -0.0305095608113487, 
-0.0297799151195076, -0.0281034022184888, -0.0255680591416587, 
-0.0222831548185084, -0.0192325578880546, -0.017138061465351, 
-0.00795388801919832, -0.00948551730810068, -0.0109260623825648, 
-0.0121071142560424, -0.0122356889667297, -0.0119671852632039, 
-0.011443080611894, -0.0103264701670775, -0.00851301891308872, 
-0.00931943327911955, -0.0107854794928235, -0.0117606665554891, 
-0.0122981126741706, -0.0128417290779904, -0.0125396201596298, 
-0.0111872791263485, -0.00944900017887592, -0.00793458358918158, 
-0.00786784513235398, -0.00775618523658388, -0.00778342378570517, 
-0.00773341111129831, -0.00755905201258847, -0.00867994788574915, 
-0.00856767887507999, -0.00839917017153023, -0.00819969133205156, 
-0.00814350875744698, -0.00810097879331339, -0.00978077696715094, 
-0.012345919771051, -0.014314367742374, -0.0158047140930344, 
-0.0171268236313219, -0.0173475238154141, -0.0168777507682366, 
-0.0171907904533275, -0.0168079013041868, -0.0155387350270384, 
-0.0136071221385007, -0.0114788899879373, -0.00928254793674215, 
-0.0159243876515305, -0.0148734801957321, -0.0110391264286132, 
-0.0161052792860213, -0.0134551059432601, -0.0159335986419256, 
-0.0128237221185521, -0.0122201811479621, -0.0109864014492699, 
-0.0100574633053536, -0.0131924278835383, -0.0093236303173408, 
-0.0159954096611316, -0.0132487448657675, -0.00997422292451404, 
-0.0131129555120115, -0.012091752490751, -0.0154676321043934, 
-0.0140171395282845, -0.0116661532536343, -0.015532882738171, 
-0.00873293716563884, -0.00712030247295228, -0.0139380125569914, 
-0.0145631170966823, -0.00831320298976728, -0.0112506766032763, 
-0.0300052299191381, -0.0245186269012974, -0.0126849066479447, 
-0.0077783651484388, -0.0291941982398039, -0.0258349210210429, 
-0.0209999658365151, -0.00885832257691175, -0.0209788315824288, 
-0.0178253431091118, -0.013385631836996, -0.0176249210382204, 
-0.029103552012985), .Dim = c(112L, 3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("11", "21", "23", "61", "64", "147", "148", "149", "150", 
    "151", "152", "153", "154", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", 
    "168", "169", "170", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", 
    "231", "232", "233", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", 
    "388", "389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", 
    "397", "398", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", "416", 
    "417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "486", "487", "488", "489", 
    "490", "491", "492", "493", "494", "495", "496", "497", "498", 
    "535", "537", "546", "550", "558", "570", "571", "573", "576", 
    "584", "586", "591", "593", "594", "597", "605", "614", "630", 
    "634", "640", "649", "654", "661", "665", "672", "675", "676", 
    "681", "682", "683", "684", "685", "686", "687", "688", "689", 
    "690", "691", "692", "693"), c("X", "Y", "Z"), c("Homo sapiens", 
    "Homo sapiens")))
```

Comment: When you say all possible combinations, Is it only pairwise `+` or include 2 + 3 + 4...

Comment: 1vs2,1vs3...
1vs2+3 (combined), 1vs2+3+4, 1+2vs3+4+5+6+7+8+9.....

Comment: @akrun please check my updated post where I explain the expected combinations and the rules

Comment: Regarding the Rules, does it mean that  combination is not needed

Comment: I do not really follow you @akrun . Running a PLS between one module and another (A1 and A2) is ok, but also running one module with the sum of two / three.. modules that will form A2 (combined).

Comment: I meant for your last section of `Rules`.  with `==` does it meant that you want both cases i.e. `Group_1 vs. Group_2&Group_3` is same as `Group_2&Group_3 vs. Group_1` except that you are passing the arguments in reverse order in the function

Comment: Ahhh ok, with those rules I meant to inform that the order is not important (Group1+Group2 is the same of Group2+Group1) and also the comparison of both blocks is the same, so that Group1 vs Group2 is the same as Group2 vs Group1

Comment: You may try `nm1 <- paste0("Group_", 1:8); out <- lapply(2:8, function(i) combn(nm1, i, FUN = function(x) two.b.pls(get(x[1]), Reduce(`+`, mget(x[-1])), iter = 999), simplify = FALSE))`

Comment: Thanks akrun, remember that the real names of the groups are not Group_1.... but `c(Frontal, Face, Parietal_L, Parietal_R, Temporal_L, Temporal_R, Occipital, Sphenoid)`. If you remember, you answered this yesterday here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199807/run-function-in-r-that-requires-two-elements-and-want-to-compare-two-by-two/69199835#69199835

Comment: Then, your `nm1 <- c("Frontal", "Face", "Parietal_L", ..`

Comment: Thanks for the info, when I write this into RStudio `out <- lapply(2:8, function(i) combn(nm1, i, FUN = function(x) two.b.pls(get(x[1]), Reduce(+, mget(x[-1])), iter = 999), simplify = FALSE))`, it tells me that there is an unexpected token `,`. In the code I see it is placed to the right of the plus symbol (+) in the `Reduce` function. Is that comma necessary?

Comment: I put a backquote on the `+`, but here it is dropped when I comment.  You may also quote it i.e. `"+"`

Comment: I do not get you, would you mind answering the question with the code?

Comment: Got it @akrun will tell you if it works

Comment: Can you add the dput of one more i.e. `Frontal` as well